# clipsToBounds not working when scaling child views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

I have a custom xib that has a horizontal stack view with 3 child views. I use this view in other xibs. When the user clicks on one of these child views, I scale it using:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

When the view is scaled, it's actually meant to appear out of the parent view's bounds. However, when I click the child view, it scales it fine, but the view is cut off.

I've double checked that all of my views in the xib have `clipsToBounds` set to false, but it's still cutting it off.

Here is what my xib class looks like:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    ... some other things that I've left out that aren't important ...

}
```

Is there something I'm missing? How do I make the child views not get clipped/cut off?

Answer (score 0):

What about the view hosting the XIB? (`CustomView` in this case). Set `clipsToBounds=false` in your `initialize`. Otherwise, take a look at Xcode's view hierarchy debugger and see if there's another view that causing the clipping.